# Unable to pass user's input value on the next page in webform using php

Tags: php, html, session

Here are codes that I have tried the last. With these codes I got nothing in input field. I want user can see what he has entered but cannot change the same. if he wants to change he has to go back to the previous page and refill the data with correct value.

**For page 1 (with php extension)**

```
<?PHP
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="index.css"/>
  <title>EduLife Welcomes You</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="title-icon.png"/>
</head>

<body>

<?php
// Set session variables

$_SESSION['dob'] = $dob;
$_SESSION['class'] = $class;

?>
[...javascript for calculating age...]
  <form>
  <h3>Check Eligibility : </h3>
  Enter Date of Birth of the child: <input type="date" name="dob" id="dob" required/><br>
  <input class="btn" type="button" value="Check Eligibility" onclick="ageCalculate()"><br>
  You are eligible for the Grade : <span id="class" class="eligible"></span>
  </form>

<a href="/PAGE2.php" ><button id="ready">OK, I want to apply!</button></a>
</body>
</html>
```

**CODE FOR PAGE 2(with php extension)**

```
<?PHP
session_start();

$dob = $_SESSION['dob'];
$class = $_SESSION['class'];
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="admn-form.css"/>
  <title>EduLife</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="title-icon.png"/>
</head>
<div id="admn-form"> 
<form action="insert.php" method="POST">
<h2  id="form-name">Apply For Admission </h2>
<h2 id="part"> Part A - Information of the student</h2>

<h3><span style="color:blue">You applying for the Grade:</span><input for="class" name="class" id="class" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['class'];?>" readonly> </input></h3>

<h3>1. Name of the student</h3>
<p class="quest">
        <label for="first-name"> First Name * : </label>
        <input type="text" Name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" pattern="[A-Z]{2,15}" required>
        <label for="middle-name"> Middle Name : </label>
        <input type="text" Name="middlename" placeholder="Middle Name" pattern="[^\s][A-Z]+{2,15}">
        <label for="last-name"> Last Name : </label>
        <input type="text" Name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" pattern="[^\s][A-Z]+{2,15}">
</p>
<h3>2. Select Gender of the student *</h3>
<p class="quest">
        <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="Female" required>
        <label for="female">Female</label>
        <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="Male" required>
        <label for="male">Male</label>
        <input type="radio" id="other" name="gender" value="Other" required>
        <label for="other">Other</label>
</p>

<h3>4. Enter Birth-detail of the student</h3>
<p class="quest">
        <label for="DOB"> Date of Birth *: </label> 
        <input type="date" name="dob" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['dob'];?>" readonly>
</p>
</form>
</div>
</HTML>
```

Comment: What do you see when you load page 2? Do any errors show up in the console? Can you see the session variables in dev tools?

Comment: Input fields at page 2 remain blank means value is not carried to this page. 
No, it doesn't show any error.

Comment: In page 1 line: `$_SESSION['dob'] = $dob;` what is the value of `$dob`? You have a form with dob field and you don't submit this form. This value is never saved to session. You should on page 1 - submit the form to page 2, in page 2 get that submitted value and you can store it in session if you want. Right now you enter dob and click a link to go to page 2 - nothing is ever stored, saved, submitted.

Comment: @sheetalsingh -  you really should start with a tutorial on PHP + forms and also `GET`/`POST`. You're missing some of the basics.

Comment: Now I found that it passes concrete values to next page but not variable user input values and javascript calculated values. E,g, 

<?php
$_SESSION['dob'] ="12-12-2012" ;
$_SESSION['grade'] = "Nursery" ;
?>

are carrying to next page but values with variable name like 

<?php
$_SESSION['dob'] =$_POST['dob']; 
$_SESSION['grade'] =$_POST['grade'];
?>

are not passed to next page. 

Please help.